# Binary Search Tree find_successor of inputNode

Tags: python, tree

Wanted to ask for feedback for my coding challenge for BST. python find_successor of inputNode inOrder.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-successor-in-binary-search-tree/
find the successor(Inputnode).

CODE INSTRUCTIONS:

1. The method findInOrderSuccessor you're asked
   to implement is located at line 30.
2. Use the helper code below to implement it.
3. In a nutshell, the helper code allows you to
   to build a Binary Search Tree.
4. Jump to line 88 to see an example for how the
   helper code is used to test findInOrderSuccessor.

```
# A node
class Node:
    # Constructor to create a new node
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = None


# A binary search tree
class BinarySearchTree:
    # Constructor to create a new BST
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def find_in_order_successor(self, inputNode):
        # check the right node of inputNode
        succ = None

        if self.root == None:
            return 'Null'
        # start with root
        while self.root:
            if self.root.key > inputNode.key:
                succ = self.root
                self.root = self.root.left
            else:  # inputNode.right:
                self.root = self.root.right
        return succ

    # Given a binary search tree and a number, inserts a
    # new node with the given number in the correct place
    # in the tree. Returns the new root pointer which the
    # caller should then use(the standard trick to avoid
    # using reference parameters)
    def insert(self, key):

        # 1) If tree is empty, create the root
        if (self.root is None):
            self.root = Node(key)
            return

        # 2) Otherwise, create a node with the key
        #    and traverse down the tree to find where to
        #    to insert the new node
        currentNode = self.root
        newNode = Node(key)
        while (currentNode is not None):

            if (key < currentNode.key):
                if (currentNode.left is None):
                    currentNode.left = newNode;
                    newNode.parent = currentNode;
                    break
                else:
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;
            else:
                if (currentNode.right is None):
                    currentNode.right = newNode;
                    newNode.parent = currentNode;
                    break
                else:
                    currentNode = currentNode.right;

    # Return a reference to a node in the BST by its key.
    # Use this method when you need a node to test your
    # findInOrderSuccessor function on
    def getNodeByKey(self, key):

        currentNode = self.root
        while (currentNode is not None):
            if (key == currentNode.key):
                return currentNode

            if (key < currentNode.key):
                currentNode = currentNode.left
            else:
                currentNode = currentNode.right

        return None


#########################################
# Driver program to test above function #
#########################################

# Create a Binary Search Tree
bst = BinarySearchTree()
bst.insert(20)
bst.insert(9);
bst.insert(25);
bst.insert(5);
bst.insert(12);
bst.insert(11);
bst.insert(14);

# Get a reference to the node whose key is 9
test = bst.getNodeByKey(12)

# Find the in order successor of test
succ = bst.find_in_order_successor(test)

# Print the key of the successor node
if succ is not None:
    print("\nInorder Successor of %d is %d " % (test.key, succ.key))
else:
    print("\nInorder Successor doesn't exist")
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because `find_in_order_successor()` empties the tree.

Comment: @greybeard Please can you show `find_in_order_successor()` not emptying the tree is a requirement of the challenge. If it's not a requirement then why would the code not be working as intended?

Comment: @greybeard, if the code produces the correct answer, it's on-topic. The unfortunate side-effect is definitely something you should point out in your review.